# How do I compare two data set which are not interrelated

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, t-test, multiple-comparisons

I have two datasets coming from the same monitoring device. One dataset measures speed based on GPS and the other measures the speed based on acceleration. Assuming GPS data is the most accurate, I need to compare the datasets to see how similar or different they are.

When data are compared visually, I can see they are different during some activities and similar in other activities. The means of the two datasets are also roughly similar. As the mean is similar, I guess the $t$-test will not give me a meaningful output. Alos the data are not random.

As I am going to get a few more samples like this, is there a way to quantify the difference between the two datasets?

Comment: What do you want to learn from this comparison?  What does "how similar or different they are" mean to you in this context?  This is (a little) too vague right now.

Comment: Do you have sets of discrete measurements such that you can say element 1 of set 1 corresponds to element 1 of set 2?  Eg, can you say that the first speed measurement from GPS comes from Alice walking home Sunday, and the first speed measurement from the accelerometer also comes from Alice walking home Sunday, etc?  Do you have all the activities that were being performed?  Do you want to compare by activity, or ignore it?  Can you provide a small example dataset to illustrate this?

Comment: Because the measurements are done using the same device, two data sets are synchronized and based on same time stamps. I have already separated the data set based on activities. This is mainly because there are pauses between each activity which has generated unwanted noise type data.

Comment: For the moment analysis are going to performed based on activities rather than whole.